# Elevator: pushed vs. pulled

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

Suppose an elevator is accelerating upward, and the acceleration has one of two causes.  Either:

1. the elevator is being pushed from below, or
2. the elevator is being pulled from above.

From inside the elevator, is it possible to tell which of 1 or 2 is the case?

I am less interested in whether it is easy or practical, and more in whether it is theoretically possible, with sufficiently sensitive measuring equipment.

Comment: "I am [more interested] in whether it is theoretically possible" - you may arrive at different answers here depending on how exactly you specify this problem. It depends on your theoretical model of the elevator and on the details of your description of the problem. Things like, is the elevator treated as an idealized rigid body, and are there constraints on it? Theory isn't a way to get at absolute truth, it's a framework that lets you conceptualize, represent and interpret the problem, and a way to make predictions based on that conceptualization and given certain simplifying assumptions.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the four walls of the elevator and replace them with strong ropes connecting floor to ceiling. If the elevator is being pushed it will collapse.

Comment: ...Nice answer +1

Comment: Interesting View,+1

Answer (score 4):

As Gandalf61 has pointed out, it depends on what kind of experiments you are allowed to do. Your question becomes more interesting if we may assume that the "elevator" is a perfectly rigid box* with opaque walls, where "opaque" means you have no means to "see" or "feel" or "hear" or "measure" anything that happens outside.

In that case, the only thing left that you can sense is the acceleration itself. And, the answer is "No." You can't tell whether the force causing the acceleration is pushing up from below, pulling up from above, or applied by a giant pair of pincers that are gripping the elevator from the side.

---

* No good attaching strain gauges to any of the inner surfaces because "perfectly rigid" means no strain, no matter how much stress is applied.

Comment: +1. I think you must extend the idealization to include perfectly vertical motion (no swaying, which can occur in real elevators). Otherwise the motion of a large mass inside the elevator would lead to different dynamic responses.